# send and read VARCHAR to a procedure in SQLSERVER from jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a `procedure` with the following structure, as on the picture.
it accepts and issues `varchar`.

[image]

I do in java code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt;
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            System.out.println("connect...");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://0.0.0.0:0000;" +"databaseName=blabla-blabla;user=blabla;password=blabla";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call xml_parser(?)}");
            cstmt.setString (1, "<xml><action>login</action><login>test</login><password>147852</password></xml>");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.execute();   

            //here I get always 0
            String s = cstmt.getString(1);
            System.out.println(s);
            cstmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("exit......!");
    }
```

I always get 0. And I do not even know if the data is going away.
lines from the procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xml_parser] 
@request varchar(max) =  '<xml>
    <action>login</action>
    <login>1</login>
    <password>1</password>
</xml>',
@responce varchar(max) = '' output
AS

begin
```

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking an actual question.

Comment: @MJH 
thank you.question added

Comment: You stored procedure seems to have two parameters, one IN and one OUT, why does your code show a call with a single parameter as if it is an IN/OUT parameter?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel need to send 2 parameter? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Use `{call xml_parser(?,?)}` and use `setString` on index 1 and `registerOutParameter` on index 2 (and `getString` on index 2)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  YEEEEAAAAAAAAHH!!!!!!!   Thank you very much. You saved me.

Comment: I combined my two comments in an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has two parameters, one IN and one OUT, not a single IN/OUT parameter.

In other words, you need to use `{call xml_parser(?,?)}` and use `setString` on index 1 and `registerOutParameter` on index 2 (and `getString` on index 2).